# Transition the numeric labels in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3.js, and I have this problem:

The following code in d3 basically draws a bar chart, with an update button that is sorting the data once in a descending order and once in ascending order. Also, numeric labels appear on the bars.

I would like to transition the numeric label from the current value to the updated value. For example, if the first bar has a numeric label of 20, and the new updated value after sorting is 100, I would like this label to transition from 20 to 100 as (20, 21, ..., 100) during the specific transition time, and vice versa, if the original label is 100 and the updated value is 20 the transition goes as 100, 99, ..., 20.

I know I can just transition the numeric value with the bar, but I would like to know how to do the transition from the current numeric value to the new update value as an exercise.

```
const data = [
  {key: 0, value: 50},
  {key: 1, value: 20},
  {key: 2, value: 100},
  {key: 3, value: 30},
  {key: 4, value: 40},
  {key: 5, value: 70}
]
// const dataset = [50, 20, 100, 30, 40]

const svgWidth = 800;
const svgHeight = 400;

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .rangeRound([0, svgWidth])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
  .range([0, svgHeight]);


const svg = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', svgWidth)
  .attr('height', svgHeight);

let bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data, d => d.key);
let labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);

bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .each(function(d){return this._old = d;})
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth)
  .attr('height', d => yScale(d.value))
  .attr('fill', d => `rgb(${d.value}, ${d.value * 2}, ${d.value * 3})`)
  .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i) + (xScale.bandwidth() / 2))
  .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value) + 20)
  .attr('font-size', 20)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .text(d => d.value);

  let asc = false;



d3.select('button').on('click', () => {
  if(!asc){
    data.sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value );
  }else{
    data.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value );
  };

  asc = !asc;




  bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data, d => d.key);
  labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);

  bars
    .transition()
    .delay((d, i) => (i * 10))
    .duration(3000)
    .each(function(d){return this._old = d;})
    .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
    .attr('height', d => yScale(d.value))
    .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value));

  labels
    .transition()
    .delay((d, i) => (i * 10))
    .duration(3000)
    .tween("text", function(d) {
      var that = this;
      var i = d3.interpolate(0, d.value);  // Number(d.percentage.slice(0, -1))
      return function(t) {
          d3.select(that).text(i(t).toFixed(0));
      }
    })
    .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value) + 20);
})
```

I found the "tween" function included in the above code for a similar but not exactly the same question. I don't know how to make the interpolation start from the current value instead of 0. I know I need somehow to store the old value, and access it in the tween, but not sure how.

Another question regarding the tween function: why do we assign `var that = this` and select `that` in the returned function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current value for each text by different ways.

For instance, with vanilla JavaScript:

```
var current = +(this.textContent);
```

Or using a D3 getter:

```
var current = +(d3.select(this).text());
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const data = [{
    key: 0,
    value: 50
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    value: 20
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: 100
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    value: 30
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    value: 40
  },
  {
    key: 5,
    value: 70
  }
]
// const dataset = [50, 20, 100, 30, 40]

const svgWidth = 800;
const svgHeight = 400;

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(data.length))
  .rangeRound([0, svgWidth])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
  .range([0, svgHeight]);


const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', svgWidth)
  .attr('height', svgHeight);

let bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data, d => d.key);
let labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);

bars.enter()
  .append('rect')
  .each(function(d) {
    return this._old = d;
  })
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth)
  .attr('height', d => yScale(d.value))
  .attr('fill', d => `rgb(${d.value}, ${d.value * 2}, ${d.value * 3})`)
  .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
  .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value))
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3)

labels.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i) + (xScale.bandwidth() / 2))
  .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value) + 20)
  .attr('font-size', 20)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .text(d => d.value);

let asc = false;



d3.select('button').on('click', () => {
  if (!asc) {
    data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
  } else {
    data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
  };

  asc = !asc;

  bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data, d => d.key);
  labels = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);

  bars
    .transition()
    .delay((d, i) => (i * 10))
    .duration(3000)
    .each(function(d) {
      return this._old = d;
    })
    .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
    .attr('height', d => yScale(d.value))
    .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value));

  labels
    .transition()
    .delay((d, i) => (i * 10))
    .duration(3000)
    .tween("text", function(d) {
      var current = +(d3.select(this).text());
      var that = this;
      var i = d3.interpolate(current, d.value); // Number(d.percentage.slice(0, -1))
      return function(t) {
        d3.select(that).text(i(t).toFixed(0));
      }
    })
    .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d.value) + 20);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<br>
```

Comment: I just realized that it makes more sense visually not to bind the data to elements on a key. This way the transition for the bar and for the labels occur synchronously. Thanks again.